# RFM Explanation - Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm learning RFM Analysis in kaggle, and found something interesting. This 'Treemap' for RFM analysis turn out not generated by plotly, somehow the size of box for each category is determined by 'rfm_coordinates' which is I don't know where it is come from. I try to swap  rfm_coordinates  value ex: Champions swap with At-Risk, Description yet changing but the size of box is not. So where this premade 'treemap' chart came from?

```
rfm_coordinates = {"Champions": [3, 5, 0.8, 1],
                   "Loyal Customers": [3, 5, 0.4, 0.8],
                   "Cannot lose them": [4, 5, 0, 0.4],
                   "At-Risk": [2, 4, 0, 0.4],
                   "Hibernating": [0, 2, 0, 0.4],
                   "About To Sleep": [0, 2, 0.4, 0.6],
                   "Promising": [0, 1, 0.6, 0.8],
                   "New Customers": [0, 1, 0.8, 1],
                   "Potential Loyalists": [1, 3, 0.6, 1],
                   "Need Attention": [2, 3, 0.4, 0.6]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (19, 15))

ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 5])

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "white"
palette = ["#282828", "#04621B", "#971194", "#F1480F",  "#4C00FF", 
           "#FF007B", "#9736FF", "#8992F3", "#B29800", "#80004C"]

for key, color in zip(rfm_coordinates.keys(), palette[:10]):
    
    coordinates = rfm_coordinates[key]
    ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax = coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]
    
    ax.axhspan(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, facecolor = color)
    
    users = rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key].shape[0]
    users_percentage = (rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key].shape[0] / rfm_table.shape[0]) * 100
    avg_monetary = rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key]["Monetary"].mean()
    
    user_txt = "\n\nTotal Users: " + str(users) + "(" +  str(round(users_percentage, 2)) + "%)"
    monetary_txt = "\n\n\n\nAverage Monetary: " + str(round(avg_monetary, 2))
    
    x = 5 * (xmin + xmax) / 2
    y = (ymin + ymax) / 2
    
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = key, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 18, color = "white", fontweight = "bold")
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = user_txt, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 14, color = "white")    
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = monetary_txt, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 14, color = "white")    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Recency Score")
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency Score")
    
sns.despine(left = True, bottom = True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

- you say you are using **kaggle** so I've based this on https://www.kaggle.com/regivm/rfm-analysis-tutorial and used sample data referenced there
- you have tagged **plotly** so you are looking for a **plotly** solution
- this https://futurice.com/blog/know-your-customers-with-rfm references how to map an RFM strategy to a text classification
- all examples of how to map recency, frequency and monetary to a quartile all use a complex strategy rather that simple **pandas** `qcut()`
- blocks can be moved around by modifying `rfm_coordinates`

  - however this will mean axis no longer represent RFM axes
  - all you have to remember is that the **list** represents two things

    1. RF values
    2. position of block in grid *ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax*

#### generate figure in plotly

- this depends on data sourcing being run and **dict** `rfm_coordinates` being defined
- have uses https://plotly.com/python/shapes/ to define boxes for strategies in similar way to **matplotlib**
- text I have uses a scatter with **mode** of text

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

df_shp = pd.DataFrame(rfm_coordinates).T.rename(
    columns={0: "y0", 1: "y1", 2: "x0", 3: "x1"}
)
df_shp["fillcolor"] = palette
df_shp.loc[:, ["x0", "x1"]] = df_shp.loc[:, ["x0", "x1"]] * 5


for segment, r in df_shp.iterrows():
    fig.add_shape(**r.to_dict(), opacity=0.6)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], dtick=1, showgrid=False),
    yaxis=dict(range=[0, 5], showgrid=False),
    margin={"l": 0, "r": 0, "b": 0, "t": 0},
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
)

df_txt = (
    rfm_table.groupby("Segment")
    .agg(avg_monetary=("Monetary", "mean"), number=("Monetary", "size"))
    .join(df_shp, how="right")
    .fillna(0)
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df_txt.loc[:, ["x0", "x1"]].mean(axis=1),
        y=df_txt.loc[:, ["y0", "y1"]].mean(axis=1),
        text=df_txt.index,
        customdata=df_txt.loc[:, ["avg_monetary", "number"]].astype(int).values,
        mode="text",
        texttemplate="<b>%{text}</b><br>Total Users:%{customdata[1]}<br>Average Monetary:%{customdata[0]}",
    )
)
```

[image]

#### data sourcing

```
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd

# use requests so that there are no issues with utf-8 encoding
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        requests.get(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/joaolcorreia/RFM-analysis/master/sample-orders.csv"
        ).text
    )
)
df["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order_date"])
NOW = df["order_date"].max()

rfm = df.groupby("customer").agg(
    recency=("order_date", lambda x: (NOW - x.max()).days),
    frequency=("order_id", "size"),
    Monetary=("grand_total", "sum"),
)

segt_map = {
    r"[1-2][1-2]": "Hibernating",
    r"[1-2][2-3]": "At risk",
    r"[1-2]4": "Can't loose them",
    r"2[1-2]": "About to sleep",
    r"22": "Need attention",
    r"[2-3][3-4]": "Loyal customers",
    r"31": "Promising",
    r"41": "New customers",
    r"[3-4][1-2]": "Potential loyalists",
    r"4[3-4]": "Champions",
}

q = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
rfm["R"] = pd.qcut(rfm["recency"], q=q, labels=[1, 2, 3, 4]).astype(int)
rfm["F"] = pd.qcut(rfm["frequency"], q=q, labels=[4, 3, 2, 1]).astype(int)
rfm["M"] = pd.qcut(rfm["Monetary"], q=q, labels=[4, 3, 2, 1]).astype(int)

rfm["Segment"] = (rfm["R"].map(str) + rfm["F"].map(str)).replace(segt_map, regex=True)
rfm_table = rfm
rfm_table
```

#### matplotlib code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

rfm_coordinates = {"Champions": [3, 5, 0.8, 1],
                   "Loyal Customers": [3, 5, 0.4, 0.8],
                   "Cannot lose them": [4, 5, 0, 0.4],
                   "At-Risk": [2, 4, 0, 0.4],
                   "Hibernating": [0, 2, 0, 0.4],
                   "About To Sleep": [0, 2, 0.4, 0.6],
                   "Promising": [0, 1, 0.6, 0.8],
                   "New Customers": [0, 1, 0.8, 1],
                   "Potential Loyalists": [1, 3, 0.6, 1],
                   "Need Attention": [2, 3, 0.4, 0.6]}

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (19, 15))

ax.set_xlim([0, 5])
ax.set_ylim([0, 5])

plt.rcParams["axes.facecolor"] = "white"
palette = ["#282828", "#04621B", "#971194", "#F1480F",  "#4C00FF", 
           "#FF007B", "#9736FF", "#8992F3", "#B29800", "#80004C"]

for key, color in zip(rfm_coordinates.keys(), palette[:10]):
    
    coordinates = rfm_coordinates[key]
    ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax = coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]
    
    ax.axhspan(ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, facecolor = color)
    
    users = rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key].shape[0]
    users_percentage = (rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key].shape[0] / rfm_table.shape[0]) * 100
    avg_monetary = rfm_table[rfm_table.Segment == key]["Monetary"].mean()
    
    user_txt = "\n\nTotal Users: " + str(users) + "(" +  str(round(users_percentage, 2)) + "%)"
    monetary_txt = "\n\n\n\nAverage Monetary: " + str(round(avg_monetary, 2))
    
    x = 5 * (xmin + xmax) / 2
    y = (ymin + ymax) / 2
    
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = key, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 18, color = "white", fontweight = "bold")
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = user_txt, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 14, color = "white")    
    plt.text(x = x, y = y, s = monetary_txt, ha = "center", va = "center", fontsize = 14, color = "white")    
    
    ax.set_xlabel("Recency Score")
    ax.set_ylabel("Frequency Score")
    
sns.despine(left = True, bottom = True)
plt.show()
```